# Using mySQL & Php in Android

Tags: php, android, mysql

Im trying to add values into my Mysql database with a Android Application here is my Php file :

```
<?php 

    $connection = mysql_connect("mywebhost.example", "user", "password")ordie(mysql_error());
    $selection = mysql_select_db("name_of_database", $connection)or die(mysql_error());

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $points = $_POST['points'];

    $insert = "INSERT INTO my_table('name','points') VALUES('$name','$points')";
    $run = mysql_query($insert)or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

And here my Android Code :

```
public void test_button (View view)
{
    new netsd().execute();

}


class netsd extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> 
{

     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
         super.onPreExecute();
         pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
         pDialog.setMessage("Loading . Please wait...");
         pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
         pDialog.setCancelable(false);
         pDialog.show(); 
     }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("country", country));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("points", Integer.toString(points)));

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://heremyexampel.com/android_connect.php");
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {


        pDialog.cancel();
    }


}
```

I dont get any problems in Eclipse but there is no values in my Mysql.So hes not adding them... I tried it with this AsyncTask but really dont get it well... For what is this

```
  <String,String,String>
```

Is it because of that ? Thank you ! (Of course Passwort server link etc are example)

Comment: no it has nothing to with those. read generic types @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: You could print the response from the server and see whats going on

Comment: So I actually can use void ? And how or where can I print that out ? You mean intern ?